# Specified worksheet not being displayed upon Workbook_Open

Tags: excel, vba

The intent of this code is to display a splash screen for a period of time and then if there is no user response it proceeds to run `Process_NWS_Data`.

What is happening is that the splash screen does not display until the loop finishes and then only for an instance.  If I uncomment the msgbox statement the splash screen appears and it seems to work fine.

```
Public TimeOut As Boolean


Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    
    Dim start As Double
          
    TimeOut = True

    Sheets("StartUp").Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Sheets("StartUp").Activate
        
    start = Timer
    
    Delay = Sheets("StartUp").Range("A37").Value
    
    'MsgBox ("Delay = " & Delay)
    
    Do While Timer < start + Delay
        DoEvents
        If TimeOut = False Then Exit Sub
    Loop
    
    Sheets("StartUp").Visible = xlSheetHidden
    Process_NWS_Data

End Sub
```

I'm expecting to get a splash screen for about 10 seconds and if the user doesn't click on one of the two options presented on the splash screen the code will execute the `Process_NWS_Data`.